# How to get the UTC + x number, according to local timezone and daylight saving?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst

**How to get the `UTC + x` number, according to local timezone and daylight saving?**

Example: let's say we're in Paris/France timezone. For a winter datetime (January 1st, 00:55:23), we expect `0001`:

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime(2018, 01, 01, 00, 55, 23).strftime('%z') 
# empty string because the datetime is naive
# expecting 0001
```

For a summer datetime, we expect `0002`:

```
print datetime.datetime(2018, 07, 01, 00, 55, 23).strftime('%z') 
# expecting 0002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io):

```
from dateutil import tz
from datetime import datetime

paris = tz.gettz('Europe/Paris')

dt1 = datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 55, 23, tzinfo=paris)
dt2 = datetime(2018, 7, 1, 0, 55, 23, tzinfo=paris)

print(dt1.strftime('%z'))  # prints +0100
print(dt2.strftime('%z'))  # prints +0200
```

Alternatively, using [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

paris = timezone('Europe/Paris')

dt1 = paris.localize(datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 55, 23))
dt2 = paris.localize(datetime(2018, 7, 1, 0, 55, 23))

print(dt1.strftime('%z'))  # prints +0100
print(dt2.strftime('%z'))  # prints +0200
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Sidenote: when the date is parsed with `strptime`, we can use: `dt = datetime.strptime(...).replace(tzinfo=paris)`.